# How to run SQL query with inside a javascript loop(map)?

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, async-await

what I'm trying to do is:

- loop through array of objects using map function
- run multiple SQL queries according to object
- append result of queries with object

I'm looping through offers which is array of object.I get `free_item` and `buy_item` which are associated with `offer`.I am using knexjs for postgresql database with nodejs

Here's actual code:

```
offers = await Promise.all(offers.map(async offer => {
        free_item_id = await db("offer_free_items").where({"offer_free_items.offer_id":offer.id}).select(["item_id"]).first()
        console.log("-----------------debug line 1------------------")

        buy_item_id = await db("offer_buy_items").where({"offer_buy_items.offer_id":offer.id}).select(["item_id"]).first()
        console.log("-----------------debug line 2-------------------")

        offer["free_item_id"] = get_item_id
        offer["buy_item_id"] = buy_item_id
        return offer
}))
```

The Problem is it is not running in correct sequence.The sequence of the output is

1. debug line 1
2. debug line 1
3. debug line 2
4. debug line 2

The correct order should be like this:

1. debug line 1
2. debug line 2
3. debug line 1
4. debug line 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `map()` iterates through your array, executing your provided function on each item and storing the results in an array. As you're passing an asynchronous function, `map()` will run the function on each item **in parallel** and return an array of pending promises, which is then wrapped in the `Promise.all` call to wait for them to finish.

If you're looking to run through your array sequentially, a simple `for...of` loop will do:

```
for (let offer of offers) {
    offer["free_item_id"] = await db("offer_free_items").where({"offer_free_items.offer_id":offer.id}).select(["item_id"]).first()
    console.log("-----------------debug line 1------------------")

    offer["buy_item_id"] = await db("offer_buy_items").where({"offer_buy_items.offer_id":offer.id}).select(["item_id"]).first()
    console.log("-----------------debug line 2-------------------")
}
```